# Unusual laptop keyboard & touchpad behavior

Tags: windows-10

I've been having issues with my laptop the past 2 weeks or so. Some keys absolutely just do not work (even after detaching the key and pressing the membrane), the caps lock turns on and off randomly, the search box in the taskbar does not auto-hide after executing a program from there, I am occasionally unable to drag tabs in Chrome or drag into a new window, taskbar previews disappear immediately after I hover over it and i cannot select a window, occasionally the cursor disappears and touchpad stops working.

I ran hardware diagnostics, with no problems. Disabled the keyboard and touchpad and it stopped the jumpy caps lock (i have a spare keyboard but no mouse so not viable solution for me).

I have a suspicion it may be a hardware issue, through overheating perhaps?

Comment: Swollen battery pressing on the circuit board, making contacts intermittent, perhaps even breaking traces. New battery & probably new keyboard/trackpad required. Take it to a repair shop & see if it's worth it.

Comment: Quick test: open the back to relieve pressure of battery on keyboard, wait a few minutes for PCB and case to relax. and see if issue is gone. If it *is* the battery, replace ASAP because of fire hazard. Depending on the model, replacement batteries may be $US25 **and up**, and some plug right in, while others are virtually inaccessible.

Comment: Battery does not appear to be unusually deformed, problem persists even after removing for a few minutes i'm afraid.